# python language server with eglot - can't get it working

Tags: python, eglot

emacs version: 28.2
eglot version: 20221020.1010

After successfully using eglot with eglot-jl for some time when programming in julia, I now have to use python for a few small tasks, and I was looking to replicate the workflow.

After reading around, I tried many different things but I cannot get this working with use-package. I want to use the pyright language server, but I cannot see how to configure it for that - everywhere I read where people say they are configuring for that purpose, they just leave it as is, which led me to assume it's the default eglot config, but I checked eglot-server-programs and it listed some byte compiled stuff (which I assume can be a version of pyright).

Additionally, I am also confused with the package names "python" for the in-built python mode and "python-mode" from melpa, as there seems to be naming conflicts at play here.

For reference, here's my configuration for julia:

```
  (use-package julia-mode
    :mode "\\.jl\\'"
    :interpreter ("julia" . julia-mode)
    :init
    (setenv "JULIA_NUM_THREADS" "4")
    :config
    (add-hook 'julia-mode-hook 'company-mode)
    (add-hook 'julia-mode-hook #'yas-minor-mode)
    (add-hook 'julia-mode-hook 'julia-repl-mode)
    (add-hook 'julia-mode-hook (lambda () (setq julia-repl-set-terminal-backend 'vterm)))
    (add-hook 'julia-mode-hook 'eglot-jl-init)
    (add-hook 'julia-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)
    (add-hook 'julia-mode-hook (lambda () (setq eglot-connect-timeout 120)))
    (add-hook 'julia-mode-hook (lambda () (setq eglot-autoshutdown t)))
    )
```

I've tried both leaving it unconfigured (and running M-x eglot manually) as it's supposed to work out of the box and the following:

```
  (use-package python
    :config
    (add-hook 'python-hook (lambda ()
                                  (setq
                                   python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose
                                   nil)
                                  )
              )
    (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'company-mode)
    (add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'yas-minor-mode)
    (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'eglot-ensure)
    (add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (setq eglot-connect-timeout 120)))
    (add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (setq eglot-autoshutdown t)))
    )
```

Both land me "[eglot] Sorry, couldn't guess for `python-mode'! Enter program to execute (or :):"

Do I actually need to install the pyright server by myself? Not even the pyright repository readme seems to imply this.

Answer (score 0):

After I specified the interpreter with

```
:interpreter ("python3" . python-mode)
```

and manually installed pyright with

```
pip install pyright
```

it worked.