# eglot with pyright server random hidden text in buffer makes pyright produces errors

Tags: eglot

I'm using `eglot` with pyright language server, whenever I write anything in the buffer that produces an error (specifically, **variable not defined error**) and then delete it, pyright still complains about it, here is an example:

[image]

in this picture it complains that **variable outjj not defined**

[image]

now when I delete from the beginning of the error line,
the same variable hidden get moved to the previous line.
I cannot delete the variable or anything.

PS: I used pyright with `lsp-mode` before but never had this problem.

**software versions**:

emacs : GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-01-01

elgot: 1.9

pyright: 1.1.166

Comment: What version of Emacs, Eglot and Pyright do you use ? I do not have this issue with Emacs 30.0.50, Eglot 1.15 and Pyright 1.1.315. Also did you configure Eglot or Pyright ? If you did, providing your configuration will help.

Comment: updated the post.

Comment: Try to update Pyright. Also check https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74713/python-language-server-with-eglot-cant-get-it-working?rq=1.